# Simple convert image to canvas not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I can't get this bit of simple code to work.  Can't see why.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function convertImageToCanvas(image) {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;
        canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        return canvas;
    }

    $('.img-class').each(convertImageToCanvas);

});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // `i` : `index` , `image` : `DOM` `img` `element` 
    function convertImageToCanvas(i, image) {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        // do stuff 
    };
    $('.img-class').each(convertImageToCanvas);
   });
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/rw8brh01/

See [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the `image` var by `this`. The `image` var that you pass by param represents an **index**. The `this` value represent the **image element**.

Note that you are just only creating the canvas element. You should append the canvas to another DOM element to see it rendered in the browser.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function convertImageToCanvas() {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = this.width;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        return canvas;
    }

    $('.img-class').each(convertImageToCanvas);

});
```

Take a look at [this](http://codepen.io/ianaya89/pen/FBdhC) codepen.